# Scrapy - download_delay change on the go

Tags: scrapy

I need to delay request in scrapy. Web page I am scraping is providing me with "Your data will be ready in 50 seconds" and time can be from 2 to 60 seconds, then I want to scrap a lot of pages (I get a list from request seconds request) so setting global download_delay to 60s is not the best idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [this](https://gist.github.com/dangra/2781744)

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.http import Request

DELAY = 5 # seconds


class MySpider(BaseSpider):

    name = 'wikipedia'
    max_concurrent_requests = 1

    start_urls = ['http://www.wikipedia.org']

    def parse(self, response):
       nextreq = Request('http://en.wikipedia.org')
       dfd = defer.Deferred()
       reactor.callLater(DELAY, dfd.callback, nextreq)
       return dfd
```

In your case DELAY will be the time you get from response.